# Get Composable function name inside it

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How can I get a composable function name inside it ?
I want to use a custom exception with the function name as a param.

```
class UnknownInfoCardTypeException(composableFunctionName: String) :
Exception("Unknown info card type was passed as a param to $composableFunctionName")
```

Comment: If you are throwing this, you can get the stack trace from the exception itself, and then get the function name from there.

Comment: You'll find it in the logs when you throw it. You can use a `contains` check on the logs to see if it contains the name of a particular Composable you might be looking for. Also, idk your use-case but this is sort of a weird way of debugging errors in your code. Why not simply use the studio debugger?

Comment: I have 'when' statement in my Composable function and at the end in 'else' condition I'm throwing UnknowninfoCardTypeException("Here I want to pass the current function name")
The reason why I need it is because I will throw it from different functions and I want to know from which function I receive this exception. 
I won't catch it. This exception should crash the app.
I didn't get how I can get the stack trace from the exception itself
Could you explain me please ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the way:

```
object{}::class.java.enclosingMethod.name
```

`enclosingMethod` is nullable so make sure to handle this case